# single channel for multiple feeds of news?

Tags: data, database, information

I subscribe to various blogs and twitter feeds which I use to parse for keywords. Many times these subscriptions do not include topics which are of the primary concern.

Are there multiplex channels to subscribe to which aggregate over a very diverse range of financial topics? Is the only solution for each person to search and hand pick these or is there a database listing possible features and statistics for feeds?